# Compare two periodic sets of data

Tags: time-series, correlation

At my company, we have two tools (old and new) to measure the same thing (user requests/hits every 5 min).  If you graph the data with time on the X axis and user hits on the Y, the data looks periodic (more requests at peak usage and fewer requests when people are sleeping).  I will have control data sets where I will generate requests, so I will know what the correct curves are supposed to look like.  But I'll also have "production" data sets which have hits for customers where I won't know what the right answer is.

I am trying to verify the accuracy/precision of the new tool by comparing it to the results from the old.  I was thinking of doing a moving average of the two data sets.  I could then compare the moving averages to each other (and  collect things like standard deviation around the moving average).

Is there a better/standard way in statistics for comparing cyclical data? I'm going to write a computer program to do this, so I can do just about anything.

Comment: What would “sufficiently similar” mean to you? Until you define that, there is not much of a way to proceed. (“It passes a hypothesis test by having $p<0.5$ is not a valid criterion for similarly, appealing as it is to have a criterion that straightforward.)

Comment: "Sufficiently similar" =~ for a sufficiently small time slice, the data points measured from old and new statistically belong to the same set (is that a T test?).  What do you think of cutting the data up into time slices and doing T tests along the way?  I'll see if I can come up with a better definition of "sufficiently similar."  The problem here is that it's hard to know how tightly to slice the data since it has a slope to it which would throw off the T test.  Something like a "cyclical T test" is what I need.

Comment: The t-test assumes independence of the observations and is sensitive to this assumption (as are common alternatives like the Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney U test). You have time series data, and the field of time series analysis exists to cope with the lack of independence.

Comment: The big issue you will encounter is that most of statistics aims to find differences. You aim to show the reverse, that there are no differences. You want to prove the null hypothesis. Unfortunately, the null hypothesis is almost certainly false, so the best you can do is get within some tolerable amount of equality. It is on you to define what you can tolerate.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!  I'll post back what I come up with.  Looking at this now to apply to time slices:  Mann–Whitney U test.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to subtract the measurements from old and new at a particular point in time.  Ideally, the difference should be zero.  Subtraction also cancels out the cyclical nature of the data since they both should have about the same slope.  From there, you can see how closely the trend is to zero, ie, find the mean, the standard deviation, etc of the difference.

You can also roughly detect data quality by counting the number outlier data points.